# Copying from a Div into an input box on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a counter with of course stop and start button. I want to make a simple time start time out and without the use of much jquery I thought of way to save it using php only with very minimal use of jquery.

On stop button click I want the div number to be copied and saved into an input textbox. Here's my code, kindly advise where I went wrong. Coz whenever I click stop it says in input textbox undefined

**Here's the HTML**

```
<div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn btn-default'  onclick='startTimer()' id='button1'>Start</button>
    <button class='btn btn-default'  onclick='stopTimer()' id='button2'>Stop</button>
    <div>
        <form role='form' action='create_delete_edit.php' method='POST'>
            <div class='dataTable_wrapper timer' id='timer' style='font-size:50pt;'>00:00</div></br>
            <input type='text' id='timerhide' name='timerhide'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Save Duration' id='btnsaveduration' name='btnsaveduration'>
            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Close Timer' id='btnclosetimer' name='btnclosetimer'>
        </form>
```

**Now here's the function o the stop**

```
function stopTimer()
{
   w.terminate();
   timerStart = true;
   w = null;
   var n1 = document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML;
   var n2 = document.getElementById('timerhide');
   n2.value = n1.value;

}
```

How will I place the value of N1 to N2 without encountering such error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do `$("#timerhide").html($("#timer").html()) `

Comment: 'value' is supported by form elements.  You can't extract value from innerHtml property. document.getElementById('timerhide').value = n1;

Comment: Your n1 var, is actually a string, not a DOM element. check my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the `#timer` div's inner text like this:

```
var time = $('#timer').html();
```

Then, update the hidden field's value with it like so:

```
$('#timerhide').val(time);
```

Or if you'd like the one liner:

```
$('#timerhide').val($('#timer').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to do this or use .html()

```
//clone
$("#newDiv").html($("#oldDiv").clone())

//html
$("#newDiv").html($("#oldDiv").html())
```